# How to dynamically change API endpoints based on the logged in user data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

In my React application. I am trying to make the endpoints configurable based on the different environment such as local, development and prod. So, to achieve that, I have created a config file with the below details-

endpoint.json-

```
{
    "User1" : {
        "local" : "http://localhost:8080",
        "dev" : "http://dev:8080",
        "prod" : "http://prod:8080"
    },
    "User2" : {
        "local" : "http://localhost:8081",
        "dev" : "http://dev.com:8081",
        "prod" : "http://prod.com:8081"
    },
    "User3" : {
        "local" : "http://localhost:8082",
        "dev" : "http://dev.com:8082",
        "prod" : "http://prod.com:8082"
    }
}
```

config.json-

```
{
    "Ramy":  {
                "id": "123",
                "user": "Ramy",
                "member": "User1"
            },
    "Joe":  {
                "id": "134",
                "user": "Joe",
                "member": "User2"
            },
   "Joey":  {
                "id": "356",
                "user": "Joey",
                "member": "User3"
            }
 }
```

I am doing the API calls in my action.js.
Here is the code-

```
  import configData from "../config/config";  
  import endpoint from "../config/endpoint";

    export const createData = (postData,obj)  => dispatch => {

        axios({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "http://dev.com:8080/api",
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              'UserData': localStorage.getItem('UserData') || 'No Token Found'
            },
            data: postData
          })
          .then (response => {
          dispatch({
            type: API_CREATE, 
            payload: response.data
          })
          })
          .catch(function(error) {       
            dispatch({
              type: SET_ERROR_DESC
            })
          })
    }
```

I want the URL to be configurable enough so that I do not need to change the endpoints for different user in different environment.It should automatically detect and redirect accordingly.

Also, I have the data in my config,json which I am encoding it and storing to localStorage. So, based on the logged in user, I would like the api URL to be configured for the speck port and environment. Can someone let me what am I missing here and how can I achieve this. Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the npm package env-cmd.

You can then create different environment variables depending on your environment.

Referenced from: https://medium.com/geekculture/multiple-environments-in-create-react-app-619bd3dc1c61

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30835483)

Answer (score 0):

In your webpack configuration, define your environment values:

```
// webpack.config.js

import * as webpack from 'webpack'

const webpackConfig = (env) => ({
    // rest of your config...
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.ENDPOINT': JSON.stringify(require('./endpoint.json')),
    }),
  ]
})
```

And you can use it in your code the following way:

```
export let ENDPOINT

try {
  ENDPOINT = process.env.ENDPOINT
  ENDPOINT = JSON.parse(ENDPOINT)
} catch (err) {
  if (err.message === 'process is not defined') {
    console.error(
      'process.env.ENDPOINT is not defined. Define it to be able to make api calls.'
    )
  } else throw err
}

// Log your environment values on app initialization
console.log(ENDOINT)
/*
{
    "User1" : {
        "local" : "http://localhost:8080",
        "dev" : "http://dev:8080",
        "prod" : "http://prod:8080"
    },
    "User2" : {
        "local" : "http://localhost:8081",
        "dev" : "http://dev.com:8081",
        "prod" : "http://prod.com:8081"
    },
    "User3" : {
        "local" : "http://localhost:8082",
        "dev" : "http://dev.com:8082",
        "prod" : "http://prod.com:8082"
    }
}
*/
```